# Facebook: post invitation on the Wall anonymously

Tags: facebook, privacy, invite

for the App we are developing now, it could be useful to find a way, when people could post the invitation to our App on the walls of their friends, but stay anonymous. For example, the post with invitation would appear as if they were sent by the App. I guess, it is not possible, but if anyone can confirm this or (hopefully) disapprove, i would be grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it is not possible. You can not post anonymously (or as an app) to a user's wall.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to send an event invite anonymously*, but it shows up in events, not the wall. I presume that it’s in violation of Facebook’s polices which generally prohibit anything anonymous.

*I just received one, today. I've also been receiving spam “event” invites from people I don’t know (presumably fake or hacked accounts) starting this past week. There’s apparently an apps loophole that was revealed last year, but which Facebook has no interest in fixing.